# JSON not being parsed and split properly in Android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse a `JSON Array` with unknown data. The `JSON` comes through like this

```
{
    "info": [
        {
            "1": "4",
            "Store #": " 0560",
            "How many microwave circuits did you run?": " 3",
            "How many new ovens did you deliver to the store?": " 1",
            "How many new racks did you deliver to the store?": " 5",
            "Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 1": " 64",
            "Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 2": " 54",
            ...
        }
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

Now because I don't know what the data will be until it's received I can't use a traditional method like

```
for (int i = 0; i < info.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject c = info.getJSONObject(i);

    String store = c.getString("Store #");
}
```

So I am trying to use this code method and I am unsuccessful

```
try {
    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

    if (success == 1) {
        info = json.getJSONArray(TAG_INFO);
        for (int i = 0; i < info.length(); i++) {
            if (info != null) {                 
                    clientList.add(info.get(i).toString());                 
            }
        }
        for (String s : clientList) {
            Log.v("CHECKING S", s);
            s.split(":");
            Log.v("CHECKING S SPLIT", s);
            values.add(s);
            Log.v("CHECKING VALUES 0", values.get(0));
            mQuestions.add(values.get(0));
            Log.v("CHECKING VALUES 1", values.get(1));
            mAnswers.add(values.get(1));                        
        }

    }
```

However my log is showing me that not only is the data not being split up and put into the `ArrayLists` as I would like it is staying in `JSON` form. Here is the logcat

```
06-27 23:32:54.479: V/CHECKING S(32540): {"Were any of the steamers gas?":" yes","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 4":" 34","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 3":" 43","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 2":" 54","Did you label all the outlets?":" yes","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 1":" 64","How many new ovens did you deliver to the store?":" 1","If yes, did you cap the water lines?":" yes","Phone #":" (740) 389-1174","Has all new equipment been installed & have you confirmed it is all working properly?":" yes","How many new racks did you deliver to the store?":" 5","Are all oven circuits tied into electrical shut down for hood?":" yes","How many Back steamers did you remove?":" none","Date":" 6-24-13","Zip":" 43302","How many oven circuits did you run?":" 2","How many microwave circuits did you run?":" 3","If yes, did you cap the gas lines?":" yes","Did you remove the existing FRONT steamers?":" yes","Did you remove the existing BACK steamers?":" no","Voltage readings on microwave circuit 1":" 57","City":" Marion","Voltage readings on microwave circuit 3":" 92","If yes, how?  Shunt Tripp  or Contactor":" shunt tripp","Voltage readings on microwave circuit 2":" 87","How many front steamers did you remove?":" 2","1":"4","State":" OH","Store #":" 0560","How many existing steamers did you remove for disposal off-site?":" none","Address":" 1318 Mount Vernon Avenue","Tech Name":" Jon Doe"}
06-27 23:32:54.479: V/CHECKING S SPLIT(32540): {"Were any of the steamers gas?":" yes","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 4":" 34","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 3":" 43","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 2":" 54","Did you label all the outlets?":" yes","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 1":" 64","How many new ovens did you deliver to the store?":" 1","If yes, did you cap the water lines?":" yes","Phone #":" (740) 389-1174","Has all new equipment been installed & have you confirmed it is all working properly?":" yes","How many new racks did you deliver to the store?":" 5","Are all oven circuits tied into electrical shut down for hood?":" yes","How many Back steamers did you remove?":" none","Date":" 6-24-13","Zip":" 43302","How many oven circuits did you run?":" 2","How many microwave circuits did you run?":" 3","If yes, did you cap the gas lines?":" yes","Did you remove the existing FRONT steamers?":" yes","Did you remove the existing BACK steamers?":" no","Voltage readings on microwave circuit 1":" 57","City":" Marion","Voltage readings on microwave circuit 3":" 92","If yes, how?  Shunt Tripp  or Contactor":" shunt tripp","Voltage readings on microwave circuit 2":" 87","How many front steamers did you remove?":" 2","1":"4","State":" OH","Store #":" 0560","How many existing steamers did you remove for disposal off-site?":" none","Address":" 1318 Mount Vernon Avenue","Tech Name":" Jon Doe"}
06-27 23:32:54.479: V/CHECKING VALUES 0(32540): {"Were any of the steamers gas?":" yes","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 4":" 34","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 3":" 43","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 2":" 54","Did you label all the outlets?":" yes","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 1":" 64","How many new ovens did you deliver to the store?":" 1","If yes, did you cap the water lines?":" yes","Phone #":" (740) 389-1174","Has all new equipment been installed & have you confirmed it is all working properly?":" yes","How many new racks did you deliver to the store?":" 5","Are all oven circuits tied into electrical shut down for hood?":" yes","How many Back steamers did you remove?":" none","Date":" 6-24-13","Zip":" 43302","How many oven circuits did you run?":" 2","How many microwave circuits did you run?":" 3","If yes, did you cap the gas lines?":" yes","Did you remove the existing FRONT steamers?":" yes","Did you remove the existing BACK steamers?":" no","Voltage readings on microwave circuit 1":" 57","City":" Marion","Voltage readings on microwave circuit 3":" 92","If yes, how?  Shunt Tripp  or Contactor":" shunt tripp","Voltage readings on microwave circuit 2":" 87","How many front steamers did you remove?":" 2","1":"4","State":" OH","Store #":" 0560","How many existing steamers did you remove for disposal off-site?":" none","Address":" 1318 Mount Vernon Avenue","Tech Name":" Jon Doe"}
06-27 23:32:54.479: W/System.err(32540): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
06-27 23:32:54.479: W/System.err(32540):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
06-27 23:32:54.479: W/System.err(32540):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
06-27 23:32:54.489: W/System.err(32540):    at com.facilitysolutionsinc.trackflex.Client$Load.doInBackground(Client.java:131)
06-27 23:32:54.489: W/System.err(32540):    at com.facilitysolutionsinc.trackflex.Client$Load.doInBackground(Client.java:1)
06-27 23:32:54.489: W/System.err(32540):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-27 23:32:54.489: W/System.err(32540):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-27 23:32:54.489: W/System.err(32540):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-27 23:32:54.489: W/System.err(32540):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-27 23:32:54.489: W/System.err(32540):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-27 23:32:54.489: W/System.err(32540):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

So what am I doing wrong? If you need anymore code ask, I'll post it. Thanks for the help

**EDIT**

Based on the answer I received I made a revision to the code. It now looks like this

```
try {
// Checking for SUCCESS TAG
int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

if (success == 1) {
info = json.getJSONArray(TAG_INFO);
    for (int i = 0; i < info.length(); i++) {
        if (info != null) {             
            clientList.add(info.get(i).toString());             
        }
    }
    for (String s : clientList) {
        Log.v("CHECKING S", s);
        String[] str_arr= s.split("[:,]");                                              
        Log.v("CHECKING VALUES 0", str_arr[0]);
        mQuestions.add(str_arr[0]);
        Log.v("CHECKING VALUES 1", str_arr[1]);
    }
    for (String content : mQuestions) {
        Log.v("QUESTIONS", content);
    }

}
```

However it's only storing the first line of my `JSON` in my `ArrayLists` now as the logcat shows

```
06-28 00:19:10.679: V/CHECKING VALUES 0(1724): {"Were any of the steamers gas?"
06-28 00:19:10.679: V/CHECKING VALUES 1(1724): " yes"
06-28 00:19:10.679: V/QUESTIONS(1724): {"Were any of the steamers gas?"
```

Comment: Where are you adding items to `values`?

Comment: By unknown data, do you mean unknown values?

Comment: @SmartLemon yes, I will never know what the `JSON` holds, or how many values it will have.

Comment: At what level don't you know? Do you know if it will have an info array?

Comment: @SmartLemon it will always have the info array, I create that, but the rest of it is unknown. Also the info array will always have a tag of "success" and it will be either  1 or 0

Comment: @SmartLemon I smell a more creative answer coming from your way... lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I have done this for you. I am just pasting the complete code below. Try it for this kind of json and it will definitely work for you.

I call the method as :

```
String data = "{'info': [{'1': '4','Store #': ' 0560','How many microwave circuits did you run?': ' 3','How many new ovens did you deliver to the store?': ' 1','How many new racks did you deliver to the store?': ' 5','Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 1': ' 64','Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 2': ' 54'}],'success': 1}";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
        populateFromResponse(jsonData);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println(" Exception occured" + e.getMessage());
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

now the implementation of populateFromResponse() method is given as:

```
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success"; private static final String TAG_INFO = "info"; private ArrayList<JSONObject> clientList; private ArrayList<String> mQuestions; private ArrayList<String> mAnswers;

  public void populateFromResponse(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {

    // parse the response   if (json != null) {

        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG         int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);         // checking for null        if (success == 1) {             JSONArray info = json.getJSONArray(TAG_INFO);           if (info != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length(); i++) {
                    // checking for null
                    if (info.get(i) != null
                            && info.get(i) instanceof JSONObject)
                        if (clientList == null) {
                            clientList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
                        }
                    clientList.add(info.getJSONObject(i));
                }           }

            for (JSONObject s : clientList) {
                Log.v("CHECKING S", s.toString());
                // Iterator containing all the keys
                Iterator<String> iterator = s.keys();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) iterator.next();
                    String value = s.getString(key);

                    print("CHECKING VALUES 0: " + key);
                    // checking for null
                    if (mQuestions == null) {
                        mQuestions = new ArrayList<String>();
                    }
                    mQuestions.add(key);

                    print("CHECKING VALUES 1: " + value);
                    // checking for null
                    if (mAnswers == null) {
                        mAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();
                    }
                    mAnswers.add(value);
                }

                print("CHECKING S SPLIT: " + s);

            }       }   } else {        print("response is null");  }

}

private void print(String string) {     System.out.println("######-- " + string + " -----#########"); }
```

Output is coming as :

```
01-04 19:38:20.332: I/System.out(7685):
 ######-- CHECKING S SPLIT: {"1":"4","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 2":" 54","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 1":" 64","How many microwave circuits did you run?":" 3","Store #":" 0560","How many new racks did you deliver to the store?":" 5","How many new ovens did you deliver to the store?":" 1"} -----#########


01-04 19:38:20.332: I/System.out(7685): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 0: {"1" -----#########
01-04 19:38:20.332: I/System.out(7685): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 1: "4","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 2" -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 0: 1 -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 1: 4 -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 0: Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 2 -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 1:  54 -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 0: Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 1 -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 1:  64 -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 0: How many microwave circuits did you run? -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 1:  3 -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 0: Store # -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 1:  0560 -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 0: How many new racks did you deliver to the store? -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 1:  5 -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 0: How many new ovens did you deliver to the store? -----#########
01-04 19:52:32.362: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING VALUES 1:  1 -----#########


01-04 19:52:32.363: I/System.out(7841): ######-- CHECKING S SPLIT: {"1":"4","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 2":" 54","Voltage readings on Turbo Chef 1":" 64","How many microwave circuits did you run?":" 3","Store #":" 0560","How many new racks did you deliver to the store?":" 5","How many new ovens did you deliver to the store?":" 1"} -----#########
```

Now enjoy the code and be happy.
bye.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to assign `s.split(":")` results to String Array as:

```
for (String s : clientList) {
             Log.v("CHECKING S", s);
             String[] str_arr= s.split(":"); //<<<<<
             Log.v("CHECKING S SPLIT", str_arr);

             Log.v("CHECKING VALUES 0", str_arr[0]);
             mQuestions.add(str_arr[0]);
             Log.v("CHECKING VALUES 1", str_arr[1]);
             mAnswers.add(str_arr[1]);                        
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You're the best. Also, now the logcat is showing I also need to split on `,` because the end of each `JSON` line ends in `,`